# The tags for the 21st century philosophy

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics, philosophy-of-mind, history-of-philosophy

What are the **tags**, if I'd like to read something about 21st century philosophy? Where do I find the list of the greatest philosophers of the 21st century? Is it true that the pure philosophy is in this century dead?

Comment: Philosophy Documentation Center has [International Directory of Philosophy](https://www.pdcnet.org/pdc-solr-gateA/app), where you can search by topic, name, department, etc. Wikipedia has [List of philosophers born in the 20th century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_philosophers_born_in_the_20th_century) many of whom are still alive.

Answer (score 3):

> Who are the greatest 21st century philosophers?

Emily Dickinson wasn't discovered until she was dead.  Mozart died poor.  The list of people whose influence rose significantly after their time is long.

I suppose finding the greatest 21st century philosophers and philosophies will be like finding the greatest musicians, artists, industrialists, politicians, horses, and athletes of the 21st century.

We just won't know until later!  But don't feel too bad... the fun part is for all of us to figure out which ones we like and to bet on 'em.

> Is it true that pure philosophy is dead?

Dismissive comments about philosophy have been made by such folks as Neil DeGrasse Tyson ([philosophy is "distracting"](https://www.realclearscience.com/articles/2014/05/22/why_does_neil_degrasse_tyson_hate_philosophy.html)) and Stephen Hawking (["philosophy is dead"](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/google/8520033/Stephen-Hawking-tells-Google-philosophy-is-dead.html)).  Christian philosopher William Lane Craig defended philosophy in [this podcast / transcript](https://www.reasonablefaith.org/media/reasonable-faith-podcast/the-conflict-between-science-and-philosophy/), making reference to the [rebuttal given by Massimo Pigliucci](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/massimo-pigliucci/neil-degrasse-tyson-and-the-value-of-philosophy_b_5330216.html).

I think dismissing better kinds of truth than verification is a dumb mistake that has bit Tyson publicly.  Fortunately, people who study philosophy have already developed the tools to dispatch this kind of abuse.

Comment: I accept your answer. But at least a list of hot topics of the 21st century should exist. Where do I start? And please do not answer by "in Google".

Comment: One starting point might be to check the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy (plato.stanford.edu) to see which articles have been updated recently, and by whom.